# system settings of Icon size selection is thowing off Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, operating-system, icons

A tester was having a look at my silverlight app and his results were nothing like I expected.  After some discussion I found out that the difference stemmed from his setting his operating system to use huge icons.  This changed the look and feel of my application.

How, in the C# code of my silverlight, can I query the Operating System to ask if the user has choosen to use huge icons, medium icons, or small icons?

Maybe
System.Windows.Icon.SizeProperty
?

Comment: SystemParameters.IconWidth/Height.  Not supported.

Comment: Can you put up a screen shot comparing the two? then we might be able to suggest a layout strategy to cater for your example (e.g. top level Viewbox etc).

Comment: Well, I have a sliderbar that I set at the bottom of the browser window.  On a resize event, I grab the size of the window to know where to put the sliderbar.  This falls apart on a system where the user has selected to ave extra large icons. I get the wrong information about the browser size and height.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your tester may have different DPI settings on their machine.  The different DPI settings will result in images/icons appearing very unexpectedly scaled.

Try adding the following code when the app starts up:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableAutoZoom = false;
```